# Why would a recursive factorial function run faster than its equivalent iterative function when using BigInt in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, recursion, firefox, bigint

While toying around with [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) in the context of implementing a factorial function, I noticed some behavior that I was not expecting. When running in Firefox, it seems as if a recursive factorial function is more performant than its iterative counterpart. When running in Chrome, the performance was swapped (which is what I was expecting to see).

I created this [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/amayer42/cec572bce36737f4e836d39b2c829d16) to show a performance comparison between multiple versions of the factorial function. Also here is an inline JavaScript snippet that is equivalent to the Gist. Note: I output the results with `console.table` which doesn't seem to show up when you run the snippet, you'll have to open the actual dev console in order to see the table.

```js
function factorialIterBigInt(input) {
    let computedFactorial = 1n;
    for (let i = input; i >= 1n; i--) {
        computedFactorial *= i;
    }
    return computedFactorial;
}

function factorialForwardIterBigInt(input) {
    let computedFactorial = 1n;
    for (let i = 1n; i <= input; i++) {
        computedFactorial *= i;
    }
    return computedFactorial;
}

function factorialRecBigInt(input) {
    if (input === 0n) {
        return 1n;
    }
    else {
        return input * factorialRecBigInt(input - 1n);
    }
}

function factorialTailRecBigInt(input, accumulatedResult = 1n) {
    if (input === 0n) {
        return accumulatedResult;
    }
    else {
        return factorialTailRecBigInt(input - 1n, input * accumulatedResult);
    }
}

function factorialIterNumber(input) {
    let computedFactorial = 1;
    for (let i = input; i >= 1; i--) {
        computedFactorial *= i;
    }
    return computedFactorial;
}
function factorialForwardIterNumber(input) {
    let computedFactorial = 1;
    for (let i = 1; i <= input; i++) {
        computedFactorial *= i;
    }
    return computedFactorial;
}

function factorialRecNumber(input) {
    if (input === 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return input * factorialRecNumber(input - 1);
    }
}

function factorialTailRecNumber(input, accumulatedResult = 1) {
    if (input === 0) {
        return accumulatedResult;
    }
    else {
        return factorialTailRecNumber(input - 1, input * accumulatedResult);
    }
}

function measurePerformanceOfFunction({ functionToMeasure, paramsToCallWith, timesToMeasure }) {
    timesToMeasure = timesToMeasure == null || timesToMeasure <= 0 ? 1 : timesToMeasure;
    let totalTime = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < timesToMeasure; i++) {
        const start = performance.now();
        functionToMeasure.apply(null, paramsToCallWith);
        const end = performance.now();
        totalTime += end - start;
    }
    return totalTime / timesToMeasure;
}

const input = 5000;
const inputAsBigInt = BigInt(input);
const timesToMeasure = 100;

console.log(`Input: ${input}`);
console.log(`Measured: ${timesToMeasure} times`);

console.table({
    'Iterative Backward': {
        'BigInt': `${measurePerformanceOfFunction({ functionToMeasure: factorialIterBigInt, paramsToCallWith: [inputAsBigInt], timesToMeasure })}ms`,
        'Number': `${measurePerformanceOfFunction({ functionToMeasure: factorialIterNumber, paramsToCallWith: [input], timesToMeasure })}ms`
    },
    'Iterative Forward': {
        'BigInt': `${measurePerformanceOfFunction({ functionToMeasure: factorialForwardIterBigInt, paramsToCallWith: [inputAsBigInt], timesToMeasure })}ms`,
        'Number': `${measurePerformanceOfFunction({ functionToMeasure: factorialForwardIterNumber, paramsToCallWith: [input], timesToMeasure })}ms`
    },
    'Recursive': {
        'BigInt': `${measurePerformanceOfFunction({ functionToMeasure: factorialRecBigInt, paramsToCallWith: [inputAsBigInt], timesToMeasure })}ms`,
        'Number': `${measurePerformanceOfFunction({ functionToMeasure: factorialRecNumber, paramsToCallWith: [input], timesToMeasure })}ms`
    },
    'Tail Recursive': {
        'BigInt': `${measurePerformanceOfFunction({ functionToMeasure: factorialTailRecBigInt, paramsToCallWith: [inputAsBigInt], timesToMeasure })}ms`,
        'Number': `${measurePerformanceOfFunction({ functionToMeasure: factorialTailRecNumber, paramsToCallWith: [input], timesToMeasure })}ms`
    }
});
```

I'm just really curious if anyone would have any clue why the recursive version of the function is faster than its iterative counterpart in Firefox?

Comment: You should be asking only one question. I suggest to drop the last one. It could be a posted as a separate question though.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @trincot, sure I can remove the second question and perhaps ask it in a separate thread.

Answer (score 2):

One reason that the iterative version could be slower is that it is not performing the multiplications in the same order as the recursive version.

The recursive version is really performing a post-order process: *first* the recursion is made, and *then* -- while backtracking *out* of recursion -- the multiplications happen. This means that the *smallest* values are multiplied first.

The iterative version loops from high to low values, so there the multiplications happen in the opposite order. When I changed this, the iterative version became some 5-15% faster, making up much of the difference with the recursive version.

One reason for that speed-up, is the memory allocation footprint (for BigInt) during the whole process: when starting with the small numbers, the initial footprint is small, while in the opposite direction, the footprint gets bigger more quickly.

Here you can see both iterative versions run. In Firefox I get better performance for the forward version:

```js
function factorialIterBigIntForward(input) {
    let computedFactorial = 1n;
    for (let i = 1n; i <= input; i++) {
        computedFactorial *= i;
    }
    return computedFactorial;
}

function factorialIterBigIntBackward(input) {
    let computedFactorial = 1n;
    for (let i = input; i >= 1n; i--) {
        computedFactorial *= i;
    }
    return computedFactorial;
}

let input = 20000n;
// Run both functions twice
let time1 = performance.now();
factorialIterBigIntBackward(input);
let time2 = performance.now();
factorialIterBigIntForward(input);
let time3 = performance.now();
factorialIterBigIntBackward(input);
let time4 = performance.now();
factorialIterBigIntForward(input);
let time5 = performance.now();

console.log("backward", time2 - time1 + time4 - time3);
console.log("forward", time3 - time2 + time5 - time4);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @trincot, that is at least a step in the correct direction. I've updated my post with a "forward" iterative version for additional comparison. I've also added a function to measure the performance of each of the factorial functions and provide the average performance so that results can hopefully be a bit more consistent (at the cost of more runtime :D).

Even with this speed improvement though, the recursive BigInt function still consistently running faster.